# gradle avoid dependency task not to run if exception occurs

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I have two tasks.. task A and task B. I want task B to run every time task A is executed. In order to do this I use finalizedBy, but if task A throws a exception still task B execute is there a way to avoid this situation.

task A {
  ...
}

task B {
  ...
}

A.finalizedBy B

Output :

Normally task A and B will be executed.

If there is exception in A, B will also be executed. I don't want task B to be executed if task A throws exception.

Comment: I don't understand. You want task B to run if A fails or not? Also please provide a sample demo that illustrates the problem :)

Comment: I don't want task B to execute if task A fails

Answer (score 3):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks):

> Finalizer tasks will be executed even if the finalized task fails.

But you can use the `doFirst` closure to stop B-task execution, if A-task was failed. Here is an example:

```
task A {
    doLast{
        println 'A'
        throw new IllegalStateException()
    }
}

task B {
    doFirst {
        if (A.state.failure != null) {
            throw new StopExecutionException()
        }
    }
    doLast{
        println 'B'
    }
}

A.finalizedBy B
```

Here is A-task state checked just before B-task execution (within `doFirst`) and if A-task was failed, then it throws StopExecutionExceptionm which is used to skip task execution.